# Initialising PHP interactive

Tags: php

I often find PHP's interactive mode—`php -a`—very useful, but it would be far more useful if I could start it and have a few commands executed right away to initialize my environment. Things like run the autoloader, set up a few `use` shortcuts for namespaces, etc.

Here's an example:

```
include "../../autoloader.php";
use App/Foo/Bar as Bar;
```

I thought maybe I could just add these lines to a text file `initialize.txt` and then start the interactive mode with `php -a < initialize.txt`, but that didn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: While not an answer to your question, do note that according to the [PHP documentation on autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) autoloading is not available in interactive mode.

Comment: Interesting comment on the doc page, I use autoloading from the CLI all the time since php 5.4 onwards...

Comment: I use autoloading on PHP5.3 and it seems to work

Comment: They repeat the same claim on the [documentation page for interactive mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php). I have found out the difference, I'll append my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Tomas Creemers mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294683/initialising-php-interactive/18294717#18294717), you have to use [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) PHP flag to auto-require a file. For example:

```
<?php
    # foo.php
    function bar() { print "Bar.\n"; }
```

You can load the PHP interpreter like this:

```
php -d auto_prepend_file=$PWD/foo.php -a
```

Session:

```
Interactive shell

php > bar();
Bar.
```

Or you can include file manually:

```
php -a
```

Session:

```
Interactive shell

php > include 'foo.php';
php > bar();
Bar.
```

Comment: Yes this worked! And I definitely prefer the `-d` approach to the `-c` approach. Thanks to both of you for getting me to the finish line on this! This will be a big help.

Comment: I've now noticed a weird exception ... I have a php loader script named "interactive" and if the file lives in the CWD and I type `php -d interactive -a` everything works. If however, I store the `interactive` file in my home directory and start php with `php -d ~/interactive -a` it starts without error but the file has not been run. Any ideas?

Comment: @ken `-d` expects an ini key-value setting, that's causes the error if `interactive` lives in your home directory. I think the first case is a 'bug', not an expected behavior. The best practice is avoid using -d without key=value pair.

Comment: Ahh yes, that was what was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *[php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)* setting [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) to specify a file that should always be executed before the actual file.

According to the [documentation on interactive shell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php), this setting is also active there.

Assuming you don't want to do this initialization for every single time you start PHP, I would suggest creating a copy of your *php.ini* file (call it 'php.ini-interactive', for example) and specify that configuration file with the `-c` option: `php -c /path/to/php.ini-interactive -a`.

According to [a comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php#108006) (by "Ryan P") on the documentation page for PHP interactive shell, `php -a` does not always do the same thing:

> Interactive Shell and Interactive Mode are not the same thing, despite
> the similar names and functionality.
>
> If you type 'php -a' and get a response of 'Interactive Shell'
> followed by a 'php>' prompt, you have interactive shell available (PHP
> was compiled with readline support). If instead you get a response of
> 'Interactive mode enabled', you DO NOT have interactive shell
> available and this article does not apply to you.
>
> You can also check 'php -m' and see if readline is listed in the
> output - if not, you don't have interactive shell.
>
> Interactive mode is essentially like running php with stdin as the
> file input. You just type code, and when you're done (Ctrl-D), php
> executes whatever you typed as if it were a normal PHP (PHTML) file -
> hence you start in interactive mode with '<?php' in order to execute
> code.

I do not have a copy of PHP with interactive *shell* available. I only have interactive *mode*, apparently. I have tested (see below) and can confirm that files configured with `auto_prepend_file` *are* executed in interactive *mode*. However, you may want to reconsider using it if you get the same symptoms as me:

```
cat /tmp/prepend.php
```

Output:

```
<?php

echo 'cookies are people too!';
```

Further:

```
grep auto_prepend_file /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Output:

```
auto_prepend_file =
```

---

```
grep auto_prepend_file /etc/php5/cli/php.ini-interactive
```

Output:

```
auto_prepend_file = /tmp/prepend.php
```

---

```
php -a
```

Session:

```
Interactive mode enabled
```

---

```
php -c /etc/php5/cli/php.ini-interactive -a
```

Output:

```
Interactive mode enabled

cookies are people too!
Segmentation fault
```

---

```
php --version
```

Output:

```
PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u2 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2013 07:56:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

(Keyboard input in that last interactive mode run is only a return followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.)

Comment: I gave this a try but it didn't work for me. Have you got it working?

Comment: Not neccessary to create a whole new ini file. `php -d auto_prepend_file=/tmp/prepend.php -a` should work correctly.

Comment: @GaborGarami: well, yes, but then it might be that `-d` works while `-c` does not. I thought I'd test the way I'd use myself (seeing as I might want to change more than one setting for the interactive mode and typing them all out is what configuration files are for) :-)

Comment: @TomasCreemers I think you have some bug in your PHP version. Start php using gdb, generate stack trace, and file a bug report on bugs.php.net. It should work as you described, even if it is not the easiest way to do that.

Comment: @TomasCreemers ... thanks for your help in getting to the answer. I have accepted GaborGarami's answer because his answer is more succinct in its solution but big thanks to you as well as you got this train rolling. Thank you!