# Provide Initial Input to Interactive PHP

Tags: php

I would like to script some initial input that I find myself repeatedly inputting when using the PHP CLI. Is this possible? I'm on a linux machine, so some form of Bash + PHP would work for me if this isn't natively supported by PHP on its own.

E.g.

```
php -a 

php > include "MyClassWithReallyVerboseName.php";
php > $o = new MyClassWithReallyVerboseName("The parameters are also pretty verbose");
```

I would like to be able to script these first two lines of PHP, so that when I execute the interactive command line the class file has already been included and the $o object will already be initialized.

Edit:
My initial search did not yield any useful results, but after I posted the question I found this useful thread in the "Related" column of my post: [initialising PHP interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294683/initialising-php-interactive)

The solution appears to be to include a define flag when launching interactive mode, including the special INI parameter [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).

```
php -d auto_prepend_file="/path/to/init/file" -a
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294683/initialising-php-interactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use the `auto_prepend_file` feature of php. Copy you `php.ini` file to `my-project-php.ini` (for instance using `cp /etc/php.ini my-project-php.ini` then edit the `my-project-php.ini` to have

```
auto_prepend_file = project-includes.php
```

the project-includes.php would have in it

```
include "MyClassWithReallyVerboseName.php";
$o = new MyClassWithReallyVerboseName("The parameters are also pretty verbose");
```

then i would run `php -c my-project-php.ini -a`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: This is close enough. auto_prepend_file is indeed the configuration parameter to use when you want to include or "prepend" some PHP code to your script. You can also programmatically prepend PHP code on the command line with -d auto_prepend_file="/path/to/file"

Comment: Thank you, your solution is definitely gentler for many use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a script called e.g. "init.php" fill in the necessary initialization code and then just include it.